How do I check if the next character is an alphabet after a numeric character in a for loop?
I am at the very beginning of my programming course (career change) so bear with me if this is simple. I am trying to check if the users input contains numbers in the middle of the string, as they must come at the end. E.g XXX55 is valid, XXX5X is not valid.
s = input("Plate: ").upper()

for i in s:
  if i.isdigit():
    if i+1.isalpha():
       print("Invalid")

This is what I tried but it doesn't work I want it to check if each character is a digit and if if its true then check if the next character is an alphabet.

You (likely) want to use a finite state machine where you track the state as a result of processing each number. Essentially you want to set a flag indicating they you have seen a number and from that point forward a letter is a problem

I assume you are doing Harvard CS 50... Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75749613/python-check-for-leading-0-cs50-s-introduction-to-programming-with-python

This is perfect thanks. I'm not quite sure what you meant by flag as I haven't learnt that yet

see the answer by @sighup below where they set the variable (a flag) v to "Valid".

It rather depends on exactly what the rules are. If the string must contain one or more digits and they must appear at the end, then you can do this:
s = "XXX5"

v = "Invalid"

for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c.isdecimal():
        try:
            int(s[i:])
            v = "Valid"
        except ValueError:
            pass
        break
print(v)

What this does is to step through the string looking for the first digit. If none are found then v doesn't change and the state is therefore invalid. If we do find a digit we then slice the string from that point onwards and attempt to convert to int. If the string was, for example, XX5X we would attempt to convert 5X to int which, obviously, would fail.
You can also use a regular expression for this but as you're just starting out....
Note:
isdecimal is used in preference to isdigit which is not appropriate in this case
